# Add values to array via foreach

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I'm trying to add values to an array via foreach but it only returns the word "Array" not the actual strings.

```
$msg = array();
foreach ($results as $result) {

     $inventory = $result->qoh;
     $inventoryOrder = $result->qo;
     $product = $result->item;
     $totalinv = $inventory+$inventoryOrder;
     if ($inventory <= $threshold) {
         $message = "Inventory for $product has fallen beneath threshold. $inventory remaining.\n";
         $msg[] = array($message); 

     }
}
print (array_values($msg));
```

I've tried a few different ways and everytime it returns the word "Array"

Comment: Use print_r to print the array... print will always only print 'Array'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [`print_r`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php), not [`print`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php). `print` is for stings only. Try this:

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r(array_values($msg)); echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: This got the array to print but it also adds in this
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Inventory for Batteries - AA  has fallen beneath threshold. 0 remaining.

        )

Answer (score 2):

Use var_dump to see the values.

```
var_dump (array_values($msg));
```

var_dump will alway show you the type of the result too. Helps a lot in debugging. (Looking at your code, I'm assuming you are doing the same).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the following code:

```
$msg[] = array($message);
```

to

```
array_push($msg, $message);
```